# SQL Server returns no data in stored procedure via ASP.NET Web API

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I use a key with every API request to ensure that the API can't be used by anyone besides those who must.

In my SQL Server stored procedure, I check if the key is correct, and if it is, it returns my data, if not, it returns nothing (`SELECT TOP 0 FROM my_Table`). But, I see that whenever I run this stored procedure, it always returns nothing. So I guess the problem lies within what I check should be true. What I need is to check if a row exists where the `Key` column = the key I gave.

This is what I've tried to check whether the row exists:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my_KeyTable WHERE [keyColumn] = @KeyParam))
BEGIN
   --return my data
END
```

I've also tried using the `SELECT COUNT()` method and checking whether the amount of returned rows is greater than 0 (`> 0`).

So to get back to my problem, my SQL `IF` statement never seems to be true. Thus returning nothing as told to in the `ELSE` statement. So any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Just ensure that you are passing the correct key. Have you checked profiler to see how the SP is executed?

Comment: @Stephen, Yes, I have tested it on plain SQL Query and also on the Web API.

Comment: @Stephen, `@KeyParam` is implemented right before the SP `AS` and written as: `@KeyParam varchar(MAX)`.

And yes, they have the same data type.

Comment: I know you probably checked it but want to ask you : Did you check your code, maybe you execute the procedure before you add the key to keytable?

Comment: Can you show the whole proc please?  Do you have `SET NOCOUNT ON`?  Not setting this can cause issues with returning results as the row count can become your actual resultset.

Comment: Another test you can do is hard code values instead of `select top 0 from table`...such as `SELECT 555,555,555,'TEST'` if you get those values back, you know the calling app is truly getting data; and its entering the `else` statement!  This narrows it down to the proc.